# How to model sensor noise in differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following system of equations which I'm using to model the orientation of a satellite while on orbit and subject to a noisy control system.

$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{\pmb{q}}&=f(\pmb{q}, \vec{\omega_s}) \\
\dot{\vec{\omega}}_r&=\left( g(\vec{\omega_s},\vec{\omega_r}) + \vec{M_c}(\pmb{q}, \vec{\eta}_\textrm{sensors}, t) \right)(1+\vec{\eta_r}) \\
\dot{\vec{\omega}}_s&=h(\vec{\omega_s}) +\vec{M_\textrm{app}}(\vec{\omega_s}, \vec{\omega_r}, \dot{\vec{\omega_r}})
\end{align*}$$

In the equations above all the $\eta$ variables are to be understood as white Gaussian noise. I believe the above to be a Random Ordinary Differential Equation and I'm numerically integrating it using the RandomEulerMayurama scheme in [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/dev/types/rode_types/). When you define your derivatives you are given access to a noise vector that comes from a Wiener process. Here I'm using that noise vector (after rescalings) in the most literal way by just introducing those noise samples where needed. $\vec{M}_c$ and $\vec{M}_\textrm{app}$ are non-linear.

For example, $\vec{M}_c$ depends on the magnetic field of the Earth at each point of the orbit contaminated with Gaussian noise to model sensor noise, i.e. $\vec{B}(t) + \vec{\eta}$, so whenever $\vec{B}(t)$ is used I just contaminate it with the noise provided by the integrator.

Is this the correct way to use and understand the noise samples provided by the integrator? Would another noise process, e.g. Ornstein–Uhlenbeck be more appropriate for the noise samples?

Here is how I compute my derivatives at each time step:

1. Calculate $\vec{M_c}$
2. Calculate $\dot{\pmb{q}}$ and $\dot{\vec{\omega}}_r$
3. Calculate $\vec{M}_\textrm{app}$
4. Calculate $\dot{\vec{\omega}}_s$
5. Put together $\dot{\pmb{q}}$, $\dot{\vec{\omega}}_r$ and $\dot{\vec{\omega}}_s$ and pass it to the integrator.

For completeness, in the equations above, $\vec{\omega}_r$ and $\vec{\omega}_s$ are the angular velocities of the reaction wheels and satellite and $\pmb{q}$ is the orientation of the satellite expressed as a quaternion.

Comment: Some notations are not defined. Please clarify. Also define what you mean by "integrator" here.

Comment: By integrator I mean the routine that is used to perform the numerical integration. Its input is a set of initial conditions and a user supplied function that calculates the derivatives at each point in time. The user defined function must take as input the state of the system and vector of noises (which are generated from a wiener process) to calculate the derivatives.

I didn't provide the exact form of the functions f,g,h M_C... as I don't think they are relevant and quite lengthy. eta_sensors is a vector of length 9 with noise samples and eta_r a vector of length 3 with noise samples.

Comment: Also : @GuillemB what is the question ? When you say that $\eta$ is white noise you are already modelling it as it seems.

Comment: I do not understand why your "integrator" (the actual name is ode solver here) should have some noise. The sensor noise lies at the measurement/sensor level which is independent of the internal dynamics of your process which you integrate with the solver.

Comment: The ODE solver provides you with noise samples at each timestep which come from a Wiener process (or another of your choice). For example see https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/tutorials/rode_example/#Example-1:-Scalar-RODEs the tutorial on how to use the RODE solver from the DifferentialEquations.jl Julia pakcagle.